# "merge layer" problem when doing GRAD-CAM. How to overcome this in my custom functional model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

This is my Model, I want to visualise the activation on the layer conv_64, what should I do?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
last_conv_layer_name = "conv_64"
classifier_layer_names = [
                          
    "concatenate_17", 
    "conv_64_2",              
    "max_pool3",                  
    "conv_64_3",                
    "conv_64_31",                
    "concatenate_18",                  
    "conv_64_32",             
    "max_pool4",                
    "conv_64_4",                  
    "conv_64_41",                  
    "concatenate_19",                  
    "conv_64_42",             
    "max_pool5", 
    "conv_64_5", 
    "max_pool6", 
    "flatten", 
    "dropout_3", 
    "dense_64", 
    "output_layer", 
]
# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(
    img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names
)
```

This is what I am doing, but getting the following error when running
The problem lies when we are concatenating two different layers and it is confusing the classifier of the GRAD CAM module...

```
(1, 360, 360, 3)
preds :  [[5.7032428e-16 1.0479534e-33 0.0000000e+00 1.0243782e-23 1.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]]
Model: "model_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_9 (InputLayer)         [(None, 360, 360, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_32 (Conv2D)             (None, 360, 360, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_64 (Conv2D)             (None, 360, 360, 1)       145       
=================================================================
Total params: 593
Trainable params: 593
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py in call(self, inputs)
    120   def call(self, inputs):
    121     if not isinstance(inputs, (list, tuple)):
--> 122       raise ValueError('A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.')
    123     if self._reshape_required:
    124       reshaped_inputs = []

ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.
```

Here is the code for the function

```
def make_gradcam_heatmap(
    img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names
):
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
    # of the last conv layer
    last_conv_layer = model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name)
    last_conv_layer_model = keras.Model(model.inputs, last_conv_layer.output)

    last_conv_layer_model.summary()

    # Second, we create a model that maps the activations of the last conv
    # layer to the final class predictions
    classifier_input = keras.Input(shape=last_conv_layer.output.shape[1:])
    x = classifier_input
    for layer_name in classifier_layer_names:
        x = model.get_layer(layer_name)(x)
    classifier_model = keras.Model(classifier_input, x)

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Compute activations of the last conv layer and make the tape watch it
        last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_model(img_array)
        tape.watch(last_conv_layer_output)
        # Compute class predictions
        preds = classifier_model(last_conv_layer_output)
        top_pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        top_class_channel = preds[:, top_pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the top predicted class with regard to
    # the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(top_class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output.numpy()[0]
    pooled_grads = pooled_grads.numpy()
    for i in range(pooled_grads.shape[-1]):
        last_conv_layer_output[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads[i]

    # The channel-wise mean of the resulting feature map
    # is our heatmap of class activation
    heatmap = np.mean(last_conv_layer_output, axis=-1)

    # For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
    heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0) / np.max(heatmap)
    return heatmap
```

Here is the minimal version for reproducing the error.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nnnHlyGbuOgNGEDvF1DY9l0vlVzgu291?usp=sharing

Looks like it will be tough when we are using concat layer and focusing on an intermediate layer...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAw8m.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888166/valueerror-a-merge-layer-should-be-called-on-a-list-of-inputs)

Comment: Nopes, this is not related to my problem. Thanks for your efforts. Also this is a functional model, not a sequential as shown in your example. I am having problem with GRAD CAM viz.

Comment: Can you add the code for your make_gradcam_heatmap function?

Comment: @kelkka I have added the code (function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that your problem lies in this bit of code:

```
classifier_input = keras.Input(shape=last_conv_layer.output.shape[1:])
x = classifier_input
for layer_name in classifier_layer_names:
    x = model.get_layer(layer_name)(x)
classifier_model = keras.Model(classifier_input, x)
```

I don't think you should call keras.Input here. Instead, what I'd do to keep it as simple as possible, is to go to your original model and copy that into a new function. Once you've done that, you can simply change your

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

in the GradCAM model to

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs=[output, conv_layer.output])
```

where conv_layer is the layer you want. Now, you'll just write

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    model_out, conv_layer_out = model(input_img, training=False)
    class_out = model_out[:, np.argmax(model_out[0])]
```

Let me know if that helps.